# Reflection or DynamicMethod?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, reflection, dynamicmethod

I have used NHibernbate in few projects and now learned about few more ORMs also. I understand that, NHibernate binds Class to Datalayer dynamically during runtime using the mapping file.

My Question is , how this late binding is done ? I mean, which Methodology is used, 'Reflection' or 'DynamicMethod' ?

In case, if it uses Reflection, Is there any ORM which uses DynamicMethod? and provides better performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of NHibernate 2.1, the [proxy factory is pluggable](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx). Here are some proxy providers supported:

- Castle.DynamicProxy
- LinFu
- Spring.NET

So proxying will be actually out of NHibernate's responsibility, and the answer to this question really depends on the selected proxy factory.

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate uses Castle.DynamicProxy, which under the hood uses DynamicMethods.

Comment: even if you specify your class as 'lazy' ?

Comment: @Frederik: 'lazy' is what tells NHibernate to proxy the entity with Castle.DynamicProxy. Otherwise it's not proxied.

Comment: IIRC nhibernate makes classes lazy by default.

Comment: @jonnii: yep, unless you define it otherwise (default-lazy="false" or lazy="false")

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how an ORM instantiates entities is not a good way to assess its overall performance.

Comment: @dario-g no just like to keep a close eye on my ORM